# Onepage navigation script needs to troggle / close on click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, nav

I have an onepage site with a responsive navigation script. Works great.
When you click on the Navigation button the "subnav" links show up. (These are anchors).

**I need to toggle/close the subnav when clicking on a link/anchor.**

Made an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/jcj0kph2/

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav').prepend('<div class="responsive-nav" style="display:none">Navigation</div>');
    $('.responsive-nav').on('click',function(){
        $('nav ul').slideToggle()
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){

        if ($(window).innerWidth() < 768) {
            $('nav ul li').css('display','block');
            $('nav ul').hide()
            $('.responsive-nav').show()
        } else {
            $('nav ul li').css('display','inline-block');
            $('nav ul').show()
            $('.responsive-nav').hide()
        }

    });

    $(window).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may tidy up your code a bit by doing the prepend and attaching the click handler all in  one statement as below.

```
var $nav = $('#nav').
    prepend('<div class="responsive-nav" style="display:none">Navigation</div>').
    on('click', '.responsive-nav, ul a', function() {
      $nav.find('ul').slideToggle()
    });
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcj0kph2/2/)

**Note:** I used `$nav.find('ul')` to target the specific nav in question as opposed to other navs that *may* exist on the page.

**Edit:** To make it not disappear when on >= 768, replace `$nav.find('ul').slideToggle()` with the following.

```
if (evt.target.tagName === 'A' && $(window).innerWidth() >= 768) {
    return;
}
$nav.find('ul').slideToggle()
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcj0kph2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the Nav to hide when you click on a link?

```
/* This executes when the nav or li (inside #nav) is pressed */ 
$('#nav').on('click', 'li, .responsive-nav', function(){
  $('nav ul').slideToggle()
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcj0kph2/1/

Comment: Thanks, but when not mobile the nav disappears. Should only happen for mobile. (Sorry, didn't added in my question)